# How does GCC know what line an error is on when the compiler takes all whitespace and comments out of the code?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I'm sure this applies to other compilers as well, but I've only used GCC.  If the compiler optimizes the code by removing everything extraneous that isn't code (comments, whitespace, etc.), how does it correctly show what line an error is on in the original file?  Does it only optimize the code after checking for errors? Or does it somehow insert tags so that if an error is found it knows what line it's on?

```
mycode.cpp: In function ‘foo(int bar)’:
mycode.cpp:59: error: no matching function for call to ‘bla(int bar)’
```

Comment: This is interesting, and funny that it never occurred to me, always took it for granted.

Comment: The preprocessor annotates its output with line numbers. You can see this yourself by running `gcc -E`.

Comment: @KerrekSB But the output of `gcc -E` is artificial, in the sense that it never exists if you don't specify `-E`.  In the early days of C, the preprocessor was a separate process, generating pretty much what you see with `-E`, but today, practically every compiler does preprocessing on the fly, while reading the input files and building the tree representation of the program.  At which point, the position in the input file is well known.

Comment: @KerrekSB And of course, even when it existed as a separate process, the preprocessor didn't remove white space, and in some cases, it didn't remove comments either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The preprocessor (conceptually) adds `#line` directives, to tell the compiler which source file and line number correspond to each line of preprocessed source. They look like

```
// set the current line number to 100, in the current source file
#line 100

// set the current line number to 1, in a header file
#line 1 "header.h"
```

(Of course, a modern preprocessor usually isn't a separate program, and usually doesn't generated an intermediate text representation, so these are actually some kind of metadata passed to the compiler along with the stream of preprocessed tokens; but it may be simpler, and not significantly incorrect, to think in terms of preprocessed source).

You can add these yourself if you want. Possible uses are testing macros that use the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` definitions, and laying traps for maintenance programmers.

Comment: In a modern compiler, there is no "preprocessor"; the lexical scanner of the front end handles preprocessing on the fly, and the compiler never sees what it would output with `-E`.  (And of course, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are intended for machine generated code; they're present in the output of lex and yacc, for example.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Hence "conceptually"; I was going to give a tedious explanation of how, in practice, it probably feeds the compiler some kind of internal representation with some kind of metadata equivalent to `#line` directives, but didn't think that level of detail would be particularly interesting.

Comment: It's not too clear what the OP was asking about, but since he mentioned removing whitespace, I assumed that he was talking about after tokenization, because white space is significant until then.  The text you added in parentheses is far better (the word "metadata" is a particularly good choice---much better than my "annotation"), since `#line` directives still affect a text representation in which white space is significant, and not individual tokens.

Comment: I didn't understand what happened pre and post-tokenization, but Mike cleared it up for me, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The compiler converts source code to an object format, or more
correctly, here, an intermediate format which will later be used
to generate object format.  I've not looked into the internals
of g++, but typically, a compiler will tokenize the input and
build a tree structure.  When doing so, it will annotate the
nodes of the tree with the position in the file where it read
the token which the node represents.  Many errors are detected
during this very parsing, but for those that aren't, the
compiler will use the information on the annotated node in the
error message.

With regards to "removing everything extraneouss that isn't
code", that's true in the sense that the compiler tokenizes the
input, and converts it into the tree.  But when doing so, it is
reading the files; at every point, it is either reading the
file, or accessing a node which was annotated while the file was
being read.

Comment: Wait, so comments and things that arent code are kept in that generated tree?  Why dosent it discard them to save nodes?

Comment: @NickSweeting Comments, not usually, but in most compilers, the nodes will contain information about where the tokens were in the source code, for use in error messages and such (and debugging information).