# Mapping between line:column numbers in C or C++ code before and after preprocessing

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor, libclang

When there's a syntax error in a C or C++ source file, both *GCC* and *Clang* report the exact line and column of where the error is. For example, if we try to compile this code fragment:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static void f(char *arg, int ignored) {
        printf("%s\n", arg);
}

#define FUNCTION(x) f(x)

#define ARG "test"

int main() {
        FUNCTION(ARG);
        return 0;
}
```

— then GCC will report an error at `7:21` (the macro body):

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:7:21: error: too few arguments to function ‘f’
    7 | #define FUNCTION(x) f(x)
      |                     ^
a.c:12:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘FUNCTION’
   12 |         FUNCTION(ARG);
      |         ^~~~~~~~
a.c:3:13: note: declared here
    3 | static void f(char *arg, int ignored) {
      |
```

while Clang will point at the macro call site (`12:2`):

```
a.c:12:2: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
        FUNCTION(ARG);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:7:24: note: expanded from macro 'FUNCTION'
#define FUNCTION(x) f(x)
                    ~  ^
a.c:3:13: note: 'f' declared here
static void f(char *arg, int ignored) {
```

The output may differ slightly across compiler flavours and versions, but, more or less, GCC and Clang are largely consistent.

Now, as far as I understand, whenever a *compiler driver* such as `gcc` or `clang++` is invoked, the preprocessor (`gcc -E`, or `clang -E`, or `cpp`) is run first, and the language-specific *compiler front-end* deals with an already preprocessed code.

If we look at the preprocessed code, however, it will indeed be heavily annotated, but there will be only *line numbers* from the original file, with *column number* information totally missing. Example:

```c
# 885 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int __uflow (FILE *);
extern int __overflow (FILE *, int);
# 909 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4

# 2 "a.c" 2


# 3 "a.c"
static void f(char *arg, int ignored) {
 printf("%s\n", arg);
}
```

So, looking at the above, we can deduce that `__uflow(...)` is actually declared at `/usr/include/stdio.h:885` (which is true), and the definition of `f(...)` starts at `a.c:3` (which is also true). You can also see that the code is reformatted (the indentation level has changed). The format of the preprocessor output is described in more detail [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html).

Now, the question is: how exactly a compiler front-end performs location translation between the preprocessed and the original code when reporting feedback to the user, given that the preprocessor output apparently contains insufficient information?

How can a 3rd-party tool (e.g.: a static analyzer) do the same, provided it can only access the original and the preprocessed code (or, alternatively, the AST of the preprocessed code)?

Is it possible using the API of [*Libclang*](https://libclang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: The question is a bit too broad to answer as-is.  The core is the misconception that the preprocessor is "run first", which is dispelled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273136).  This question also asks about column info, but for two compilers, and the answer is not the same for both.  It also asks about getting the info from libclang, which should be a separate question.  I suggest narrowing the question by either asking about how one compiler tracks macro/column info, or asking about libclang only.  (And be aware that Clang has two APIs: libclang for C, libtooling for C++.)

Comment: @ScottMcPeak, you're right, thank you.

It's only now that it occurred to me that _Libclang_ actually reports locations in the original code (before the preprocessor is run).

Let's close this question.